# How to determin how much space is freeon your server? (php)

Tags: php, apache, space

So I have  Apache Web Hosting from some provider. how to determin how much freespace (mb's) for hosting files I have using php function?

Comment: How any given provider decides how much space you have is entirely up to them.  You'll have to ask your provider what the best way for you to check their limits is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[disk_free_space](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)