# php disk_total_space() minus disk_free_space() does not equal occupied space

Tags: php, filesystems, size, hp-ux

I wanted to check space available on the storage, where I'm storing users' attachments. I went with [`disk_free_space()`](http://php.net/disk_free_space/) and [`disk_total_space()`](http://php.net/disk_total_space/). The result is:

> Free space: 5.47 GB
>   Total space: 5.86 GB

So the space occupied = **0.39 GB**.

I also looped through the files to catch their size with [`filesize()`](http://php.net/filesize/). In total the files occupy **18.34 GB**. (The maximum file size is 4 MB, so the note in the PHP manual regarding 2GB does note apply)

So:

> Total space - Free space **!=** Occupied space

Why?

The filesystem is on HP-UX. I measured all all the values using the same account - I ran all the command from a php script, by executing the script with an internet browser.

I also checked the functions in Windows. The results were OK.

I went through some other questions related to the functions ( [How to get the disk space on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425841/how-to-get-the-disk-space-on-a-server), [How to determin how much space is freeon your server? (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806866/how-to-determin-how-much-space-is-freeon-your-server-php), [How to detect the server space enough for the uploaded file or no?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199513/how-to-detect-the-server-space-enough-for-the-uploaded-file-or-no), [How to get the disk space on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425841/how-to-get-the-disk-space-on-a-server), [Is it possible to get special Local Disk information from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713893/is-it-possible-to-get-special-local-disk-information-from-php), [php disk_total_space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466140/php-disk-total-space)), but did not find an answer.

Comment: I think Ur system has some partitions, try disk_free_space('/home/') and disk_total_space('/home/')

Comment: @Sergey Thanks. They both returned `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the OS and the used filesystem this highly depends on the directory you call the functions with. The reason is, that linux mounts several drives into one big tree. You cannot just call `disk_total_space('/')`, because this only gives you the size of the root partition. Try `disk_total_space($attachmentFolder);`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I was trying to find the OS related info and tips in the PHP manual but did not make it. Did I miss it? Could you provide a source where I could learn more about it?

Comment: Hard to tell ^^ Thats just how *NIX-based OS organize theire filesystem (like mentioned all in one tree). One problem, that occurs, is that not every "filesystem" is "real". There are virtual filesystems, like the one for the devices (usually `/dev`), or processes (`/proc`), that don't have a size at all (or infinite, depends on the point of view). This means, that if a FS-related operation always affects every mounted filesystem, it may end not very well... Thus, don't know, maybe `man mount` http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount as source?)